# Http handlers in Mule

Tags: mule-esb

I want to apply the security to my API end points in mule. Is there any way we can write an `http` handler in mule?

So that I no need to replicate the code for each API and all my inbound requests can be handled through that handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom policy in anypoint studio and apply same custom policy in API Manager.

https://dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-policies-in-mulesoft

https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/howto/howto-custom-api-policy-with-anypoint-platform/

Thanks,

Manish Yadav

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use couldhub policies for the same.
2. You can write your custom java code and use java component